# Custom Dropdown Attibute in Custom Module In magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.1.0, and i created one custom module.  i created form through ui_component. now i want to create one city dropdown and one status is_active field.

How is this both possible with Ui_component?

For Status:

```
<field name="is_active">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Model\Page\Source\IsActive</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array"><item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">false</item>
    </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
            </item>
    </argument>
    </field>
```

For City Dropdown:

```
field name="city">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">city</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Comment: please add your code of ui_component, which you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, now check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

You need to add

```
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Your\Module\Model\SomeFile</item>
```

So your field code

```
<field name="city">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Your\Module\Model\SomeFile</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">City</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">city</item>
            <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">-- Please Select --</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

And your module should like this

```
<?php
namespace Your\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

/**
 * Class IsActive
 */
class SomeFile implements OptionSourceInterface
{

    /**
     * Get options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {

            $options = [
                [
                'label' => 'Test',
                'value' => '1',
                ],
                [
                'label' => 'Test2',
                'value' => '2',
                ]
            ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for Reply. I tried like this, but it is showing error like xxx\xxx\Model\City\CityOption.php does not exist

Comment: can you clear var/generation folder and flush cache and try

Comment: I did that, then also showing same error

Comment: can you show your CityOption.php file

Comment: in that file i just change class and namespace, according to your refered code

Comment: @sam, the code is correct, just use `<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Your\Module\Model\SomeFile</item>` instead of `<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Your\Module\Model\SomeFile.php</item>`

Comment: @JaiminSutariya , i tried with that changes, then also getting same error

Comment: @sam pls check my updated answer

Comment: One more thing, when i select the option, it is not saved.